# create view aggregating 3 collections with a concatenation

Tags: mongodb, view, aggregate-functions, mongodb-lookup

I have 3 collections. I would like to create a view that would tell me if the image file of the image collection is used on another collection.

Images

```
        "_id": "65018e77b4f945eb41faff44",
        "fileName": "file01.webp",
        "size": "66K",
        "createdDate": 1694600823,
        "updatedDate": 1694600823,
        "deleted": "",
        "sizeNumber": 67340
```

Mags

```
{
        "_id": "64fb1db918be726025f1fb9e",
        "title": "LES FEUILLES MORTES",
        "imageVertical": "/assets/uploads/file04.webp",
        "affiche": "/assets/uploads/file46.webp",
        "teaserImages": [
            "/assets/uploads/file32.webp",
            "/assets/uploads/file45.webp",
            "/assets/uploads/file12.webp"
        ],
        "releaseDate": 1694178264.818,
        "subtitle": "« Le génie d'Aki Kaurismäki est de savoir trenscender un univers sinistre avec un humour succulent et une poésie incomparable. »",
        "createdDate": 1694178745,
        "updatedDate": 1694179009,
        "deleted": "",
        "validated": true
    }
```

Movies

```
    {
        "_id": "6489f0c118be726025f1ee35",
        "category": "red",
        "title": "Interdit aux chiens et aux Italiens",
        "image": "/assets/uploads/file11.webp",
        "imageCard": "/assets/uploads/file24.webp",
        "director": "Alain Ughetto",
        "distributor": "Gebeka",
        "releaseDate": 1674601200,
        "videoLink": "https://player.vimeo.com/video/515151515845",
        "videoDlLink": "https://joon.doe",
        "imagesDlLink": "",
        "pressKitDlLink": "https://joon.doe",
        "createdDate": 1686761665,
        "updatedDate": 1686761959,
        "deleted": "",
        "validated": true,
        "__v": 0
    }
```

a convenient ouput would be :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "65018e77b4f945eb41faff44",
    "fileName": "file01.webp",
    "size": "66K",
    "createdDate": 1694600823,
    "updatedDate": 1694600823,
    "deleted": "",
    "sizeNumber": 67340,
    "used": {
      "movies": {
        "_id": "74118e77b4f945eb41faff24",
        "imageCard": "/assets/uploads/file01.webp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "65018e77b4f945eb41faff44",
    "fileName": "file32.webp",
    "size": "66K",
    "createdDate": 1694600823,
    "updatedDate": 1694600823,
    "deleted": "",
    "sizeNumber": 67340,
    "used": {
      "mags": {
        "_id": "21218e77b4f945eb41faff54",
        "imageVertical": "/assets/uploads/file32.webp"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I can't get it working... I don't know if I messed up the concatenation at some point  `{ "$concat": ["/assets/uploads/", "$fileName"] } }` but I didn't manage to have any decent output

One of my attempt was this in the hope of having a way of connecting 2 collections on a few parameters :

```
db.images.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "mags",
      let: { fileNameWithPrefix: { $concat: ["/assets/uploads/", "$fileName"] } },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                { $eq: ["$imageVertical", "$$fileNameWithPrefix"] },
                { $eq: ["$imageHorizontal", "$$fileNameWithPrefix"] },
                { $eq: ["$affiche", "$$fileNameWithPrefix"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            fileName: 1,
            size: 1,
            createdDate: 1,
            updatedDate: 1,
            deleted: 1,
            sizeNumber: 1,
            fileNameWithPrefix: 1,
            affiche: 1,
            imageHorizontal: 1,
            imageVertical: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "joinedData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$joinedData"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      idMag: "$joinedData._id",
      imageHorizontal: "$joinedData.imageHorizontal",
      imageVertical: "$joinedData.imageVertical",
      affiche: "$joinedData.affiche",
      fileName: 1,
      size: "$joinedData.size",
      createdDate: "$joinedData.createdDate",
      updatedDate: "$joinedData.updatedDate",
      deleted: "$joinedData.deleted",
      sizeNumber: "$joinedData.sizeNumber"
    }
  }
]);
```

here is the output :

```
[{
        "_id": "65018e77b4f945eb41fafde5",
        "fileName": "file08.webp",
        "idMag": "6475eefaa801c7bf4f5b8ee3",
        "imageVertical": "/assets/uploads/file31.webp",
        "affiche": "/assets/uploads/file08.webp",
        "createdDate": 1685450490,
        "updatedDate": 1685450490,
        "deleted": ""
    },
    {
        "_id": "65018e77b4f945eb41fafdff",
        "fileName": "file12.webp",
        "idMag": "6475f502a801c7bf4f5b8f15",
        "imageVertical": "/assets/uploads/file12.webp",
        "affiche": "/assets/uploads/file86.webp",
        "createdDate": 1685452034,
        "updatedDate": 1685549150,
        "deleted": ""
    }]
```

This output is not bad, I still try to find a way of getting the matches from insied the array of the mags collection of the value "teaserImages"

I tried this :

```
db.images.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "mags",
      let: { fileNameWithPrefix: { $concat: ["/assets/uploads/", "$fileName"] } },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                { $eq: ["$imageVertical", "$$fileNameWithPrefix"] },
                { $eq: ["$imageHorizontal", "$$fileNameWithPrefix"] },
                { $eq: ["$affiche", "$$fileNameWithPrefix"] },
                {$in: ["$$fileNameWithPrefix", "$teaserImages"]}
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            fileName: 1,
            size: 1,
            createdDate: 1,
            updatedDate: 1,
            deleted: 1,
            sizeNumber: 1,
            fileNameWithPrefix: 1,
            affiche: 1,
            imageHorizontal: 1,
            imageVertical: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "joinedData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$joinedData"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      idMag: "$joinedData._id",
      imageHorizontal: "$joinedData.imageHorizontal",
      imageVertical: "$joinedData.imageVertical",
      affiche: "$joinedData.affiche",
      fileName: 1,
      size: "$joinedData.size",
      createdDate: "$joinedData.createdDate",
      updatedDate: "$joinedData.updatedDate",
      deleted: "$joinedData.deleted",
      sizeNumber: "$joinedData.sizeNumber"
    }
  }
]);
```

here is the output :

```
{
    "message" : "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 40081,
    "codeName" : "Location40081"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your current query/attempt?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just added one of my last query attempt

Comment: Maybe I just should create a specific endpoint and do the logic in node...

Comment: You are performing joining the `mags` collection with `images` collection. The `let` is used to declare the variables for the LEFT collection (mags)'s field but you are declaring the field from the `images` collection. Note that I see your data "/assets/uploads/file01.webp" didn't match any 3 conditions, so that's why the `joinedData` is empty. And when `$unwind` `joinedData`, this will return no document. You should use the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true` in `$unwind` stage.  [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RKa8K39x7du)

Comment: Thanks, I did manage to have some result inversing the mags and the images collection, the data I found seems coherent. But I don't know how to look into the teaserImages array to look for some matches.

Comment: Use `$in` operator. And before that you need to declare the variable similar as what 
we did in `let`. `$in: ["<fieldToCompare>", "$$teaserImage"]`

Answer (score 0):

My last attempt works fine to aggregates 2 of the collections.
I will be using 2 queries and then I will concatenate the 2 result to have a 3 collection aggregation.

The last error that I had "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing" was just because for some reason there were a few test cases where the array was missing in the document, I deleted this documents that were not relevant and the aggregation worked fine as intended. Here is the output :

```
[{
        "_id": "65018e77b4f945eb41fafdd1",
        "fileName": "file-00.webp",
        "idMag": "6461d440a801c7bf4f5b8873",
        "imageVertical": "/assets/uploads/file-30.webp",
        "affiche": "/assets/uploads/file-e2.webp",
        "createdDate": 1684132928,
        "updatedDate": 1685528018,
        "deleted": "",
        "teaserImages": [
            "/assets/uploads/file-6a.webp",
            "/assets/uploads/file-00.webp",
            "/assets/uploads/file-19.webp"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "65018e77b4f945eb41fafde5",
        "fileName": "file-0a.webp",
        "idMag": "6475eefaa801c7bf4f5b8ee3",
        "imageVertical": "/assets/uploads/file-3b.webp",
        "affiche": "/assets/uploads/file-0a.webp",
        "createdDate": 1685450490,
        "updatedDate": 1685450490,
        "deleted": "",
        "teaserImages": []
    }]
```

for this last updated query :

```
db.images.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "mags",
      let: { fileNameWithPrefix: { $concat: ["/assets/uploads/", "$fileName"] } },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                { $eq: ["$imageVertical", "$$fileNameWithPrefix"] },
                { $eq: ["$imageHorizontal", "$$fileNameWithPrefix"] },
                { $eq: ["$affiche", "$$fileNameWithPrefix"] },
                {$in: ["$$fileNameWithPrefix", "$teaserImages"]}
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            fileName: 1,
            size: 1,
            createdDate: 1,
            updatedDate: 1,
            deleted: 1,
            sizeNumber: 1,
            fileNameWithPrefix: 1,
            affiche: 1,
            imageHorizontal: 1,
            imageVertical: 1,
            teaserImages: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "joinedData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$joinedData"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      idMag: "$joinedData._id",
      imageHorizontal: "$joinedData.imageHorizontal",
      imageVertical: "$joinedData.imageVertical",
      affiche: "$joinedData.affiche",
      fileName: 1,
      size: "$joinedData.size",
      createdDate: "$joinedData.createdDate",
      updatedDate: "$joinedData.updatedDate",
      deleted: "$joinedData.deleted",
      sizeNumber: "$joinedData.sizeNumber",
      teaserImages: "$joinedData.teaserImages"
    }
  }
]);
```